# can somebody explain the sequence of start to end of data stages in databricks in MS Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, databricks, azure-databricks

I am learning Databricks in MS azure and have been given 4 steps to complete a task:

1. Upload a csv file (identify the relevant dataset yourself) into dbfs
2. Perform some of the basics transformational activities on the data set
3. Finally save the output Into The Delta tables of the data bricks
4. Once the delta table is created implemented unit testing (with certain test cases like count column profiling pytest can used for any other module) in databricks

I did first step but then for second step i was told to create a dataframe and do sql activity through delta table which I was not aware of. Can somebody share the sequence of what needs to be done while working on databricks

Answer (score 0):

Load the csv into a dataframe

```py
df =( spark.read.format('csv')
      .option("header","true")
      .load('dbfs:/path_to_csv/filename.csv')
    )
```

From there, you can save it to a Delta Table :

```py
df.write.format("delta").save("/mnt/delta/filename")
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE delta_table_name USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/delta/filename/'")
```

and use some Spark SQL to query and analyze the data :

```py
# In Python
df = spark.table("delta_table_name")
display(df.groupBy('some_column')
          .count()
          .orderBy('count', ascending=False))
```

Or you can  query it with SQL commands (starting the cell with %sql )

```sql
%sql
SELECT * FROM delta_table_name
```